# Concat two Prometheus metrics in one Grafana gauge

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I would like to combine two Prometheus metrics in one Grafana gauge (it could be also a single stat or other panel) and wondering what's the best way to do this. I have two Prometheus metrics: `activeNodes` and `totalNodes`. What I would like to have is a gauge that would take the max value from `totalNodes` and display in its body a concatenated status like: `activeNodes/totalNodes` e.g. `10/10`. Any hints on how to go about this would be apprecatied.

Comment: AFAIK, there is current no way to achieve that. The nearest are the `SingleStat Math` and `Percent+` plugins. You can also have a rich display with `Status By Group Panel`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment - I was afraid there is no such feature yet. The thread below confirms it: https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/4929